# How to find a specific string in a web page which is between two particular strings using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, web-scraping

Say I am scraping www.website.com. Using these two lines of codes,

```
page = requests.get(www.website.com)
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
```

I have stored the whole source into `tree`. Now, `tree` is obviously full of texts and tags and html stuff. I am only interested in one particular string which is between two other strings, say `start` and `end`, and does NOT include one specific `word`. How can I do that?

Comment: please give us your entire code. What is the value html? what is this website? What is that specific 'word'?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the specific format of the website you're scraping, the only way i can think to do it is to do a depth-first concatenation of the content of the html elements in the tree. Then search that concatenation for "start", record that index, search for "end", record that index, and then take a substring between the two indices.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
>>> tree = "This is the start and end"
>>> tree.split('start')[-1].split('end')[0]
' and '
```